# ¿Por qué me da error al enviar npm start?

Tags: reactjs, npm, línea-de-comandos

Estaba corriendo `npx create-react-app (nombre del proyecto)`, ya lo había ejecutado previamente en mi computador y no me había dado problemas. Ahora lo ejecuté y al finalizar iba a correr `npm start` como es costumbre para verificar que todo se actualizó correctamente y me mostró los errores que se ven en la imagen.

Agradezco si alguien que me pueda ayudar a cómo resolverlo, ya que no encuentro respuesta concreta, cada sitio dice algo distinto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas seguro que estes en la carpeta del proyecto?

Comment: necesitas entrar en la carpeta del proyecto que has creado en el Desktop

Answer (score 2):

**No estas en la carpeta del proyecto.**

Cuando estas en un directorio y ejecutas:

```
npx create-react-app nombre_del_proyecto
```

creas el directorio `nombre_del_proyecto` con todos los ficheros en su interior, debes entrar con:

```
cd nombre_del_proyecto
```

antes de ejecutar

```
npm start
```

Tu error indica que no se encuentra el fichero `package.json` necesario para arrancar la aplicación (contiene las dependencias y scrips necesarios) y que no esta en tu ubicación actual sino dentro de la carpeta de proyecto que has creado.